# How to fetch data from supabase

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

I tried this by exploring web and supabase docs but nothing really happens

```
import 'package:supabase/supabase.dart';

class supahandelar {
  static const SupaUrl = 'UrlFromSupabase';
  static const SupaKey = 'KeyFromSupabase';

  final client = SupabaseClient(SupaUrl, SupaKey);
  getData() async {
    var response = await client.from('Pokemons').select().execute();
    print("Respnse");
    print(response);
    
  }
}
```

It gives me this output on console:

> instance of 'minified:hy<erased>'

Also not getting any output in widgets/ui

Can anyone please suggest me simple methods to only fetch data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just an RSL issues. When i tried with new databases without RSL disabled it worked.

So i need to create RSL Policy of who to allow read data...
For Ex:-I Added true for all user to read

If anyone face this issue please check/ Create RSL Policy.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with the same problem as you and couldn't find the issue.